# How to automatically escape unicode characters in Java property files using Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, unicode, properties-file

I'm translating a **Java** application by using a `ResourceBundle` with various `*.properties` files. Now I like to have a **Gradle** task or want to modify a task to automatically escape any *unicode* character by replacing it with its *ASCII* representation, something like Java's `native2ascii` tool does.

This is what I'm done so far with my build file, but the **output remains unescaped**:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.EscapeUnicode

tasks.withType(ProcessResources) {
    filesMatching('**/*.properties') {
        println "\t-> ${it}"
        filter EscapeUnicode
    }
}
```

*Any help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 6):

You can do it providing the additional copy specification for properties files, this way:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.EscapeUnicode
tasks.withType(ProcessResources).each { task ->
    task.from(task.getSource()) {
        include '**/*.properties'
        filter(EscapeUnicode)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a life-saver.

Answer (score 0):

[The solution given by stanislav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743251/777714) caused me duplicate file conflicts (I think this creates a new "pipeline" from the same source files, only including 'properties' files, filtering, and writing to the same dir as the original task, but the original "pipelines" of the task stay unchanged).

For anyone looking to do this without duplication, here is my solution. It is also using `Native2AsciiFilter` instead of `EscapeUnicode` which should give a more similar result to `native2ascii` maven tool. This filter works on lines and not on files (it does not extend `java.io.FilterReader`), so we can't use it directly as a parameter of `filter`.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.Native2AsciiFilter
tasks.withType(ProcessResources).each { task ->
    def nativeToAscii = new Native2AsciiFilter()
    task.filesMatching('**/*.properties') {
        filter { line -> nativeToAscii.filter(line) }
    }
}
```