# gradle: how to process resource bundle properties native2ascii?

Tags: gradle, resources, bundle, message

gradle: how to process resource bundle properties?

```
 resources/messages.properties
           native/messages_fr.properties
```

In ant, there is a task "native2ascii" for this purpose. Do I need to do anything to transform the native messages for gradle?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743251/320911

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically escape unicode characters in Java property files using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729847/how-to-automatically-escape-unicode-characters-in-java-property-files-using-grad)